# Installing Web3 stuck on fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule http-https@1.0

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3j, ubuntu

[image]

I am trying to install web3 for ethereum but it keeps sticking on this *fetchMetadata*

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of npm otherwise you can install the latest version with:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

Another method is to install yarn and try it that way, you can install yarn with the following line:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

And if you are using proxy you'll need to clear your https proxy settings:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-prox
```